# Error: Object with ID 'Participant:01' in collection with ID '$sysregistries' does not exist

Tags: javascript, hyperledger-composer

I am trying to build a business model in Hyperledger Composer. I have 2 participants: vendor and customer as well as one asset which is Delivery. I have 2 transactions: createDelivery and receiveDelivery. createDelivery creates the asset and receiveDelivery changes the status of the Delivery.

The customer has field Inventory and my goal is to make so that when receiveDelivery transaction is passed, the Inventory field in customer asset is updated by the Quantity of the Delivery.

I am getting an error when trying to invoke confirmDelivery and the error is as follows:  Note that 01 is the ID of customer.

Here is my model file:

```
namespace org.example

participant customer identified by CompanyID {

  o String CompanyID
  o String Name
  o Integer Inventory
}

participant vendor identified by CompanyID {

  o String CompanyID
  o String Name
}

asset Delivery identified by DeliveryID {

  o String DeliveryID
  o String Material
  o Integer Quantity
  o DeliveryStatus Status
  --> vendor vendor
  --> customer customer

}

 enum DeliveryStatus {

 o Created
 o Received

}

transaction createDelivery { 

  o String DeliveryID
  o String Material
  o Integer Quantity
  --> vendor vendor
  --> customer customer
}

transaction receiveDelivery { 
  --> Delivery Delivery
}
```

Below is the script file:

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Create Delivery.
 * @param {org.example.createDelivery} createDelivery 
 * @transaction
 */

 async function createDelivery(createDelivery) { // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
    const factory = getFactory();
    const NS = 'org.example';

    var delivery = factory.newResource(NS, 'Delivery', createDelivery.DeliveryID);

    delivery.customer = factory.newRelationship(NS, 'customer', createDelivery.customer.getIdentifier());
    delivery.vendor = factory.newRelationship(NS, 'vendor', createDelivery.vendor.getIdentifier());

    delivery.Material = createDelivery.Material;
    delivery.Quantity = createDelivery.Quantity;
    delivery.Status = "Created";

    //save the asset
    const assetRegistry = await getAssetRegistry(delivery.getFullyQualifiedType());
    await assetRegistry.add(delivery);

 }

  /**
 * Receive Delivery.
 * @param {org.example.receiveDelivery} receiveDelivery 
 * @transaction
 */

 async function receiveDelivery(receiveDelivery) { // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
    const factory = getFactory();
    const NS = 'org.example';

    var delivery = receiveDelivery.Delivery
    var quantity = delivery.Quantity
    const customer = await getParticipantRegistry(delivery.customer.getIdentifier());

    customer.Inventory += quantity;
    await customer.update(customer)

    delivery.Status = 'Received'

 }
```

Default ACL:

```
rule NetworkAdminUser {
    description: "Grant business network administrators full access to user resources"
    participant: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin"
    operation: ALL
    resource: "**"
    action: ALLOW
}

rule NetworkAdminSystem {
    description: "Grant business network administrators full access to system resources"
    participant: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin"
    operation: ALL
    resource: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.**"
    action: ALLOW
}

rule GrantSysAccess {
     description: "Grant access to all Participants to target system registries"
     participant: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.Participant"
     operation: ALL
     resource: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.**"
     action: ALLOW
   }
```

I've been trying to solve this error for an hour already and would appreciate if you could help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

There were a few errors with your `receive` transaction, but the code below should work.

Some notes:

1. You need to get the registry (asset or participant) by its namespace before trying to update it
2. The customer registry you then need to get the specific customer before trying to update.
3. For the delivery asset, you already have that passed as a parameter so you don't need to get that specific asset
4. You have used a lowercase 'c' for your customer class and 'v' for vendor class then used an uppercase 'D' for delivery which is a bit confusing.

> Code Example

```
 /**
 * Receive Delivery.
 * @param {org.example.receiveDelivery} receiveDelivery 
 * @transaction
 */

 async function receiveDelivery(receiveDelivery) { // eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars
 //   const factory = getFactory();
 const NS = 'org.example';

 var delivery = receiveDelivery.Delivery;
 var quantity = delivery.Quantity;

 //Get The Customer Participant Registry, get the Specific Customer, then update  
 const customerRegistry = await getParticipantRegistry(NS+'.customer');
 var customer = await customerRegistry.get( delivery.customer.getIdentifier() );
 customer.Inventory += quantity;
 await customerRegistry.update(customer);

 //Get the Delivery Asset registry, then Update   
 const deliveryRegistry = await getAssetRegistry(NS+'.Delivery');
 delivery.Status = 'Received';
 await deliveryRegistry.update(delivery);
```